# Find locus of point of intersection of $x+2y+\lambda(x-2y)=0$, $x+y-2+\beta(x-2)=0$, if these are always perpendicular to each other.

Tags: analytic-geometry, circles, solution-verification

Find locus of point of intersection of $x+2y+\lambda(x-2y)=0$, $x+y-2+\beta(x-2)=0$, if these are always perpendicular to each other.

My attempt is as follows:-

$x+2y+\lambda(x-2y)=0$, if we see carefully this represents the family of lines which pass through the intersection of $x+2y=0$ and $x-2y=0$ which is $(0,0)$

In the same way $x+y-2+\beta(x-2)=0$ represents family of lines which pass through the intersection of $x+y-2=0$ and $x-2=0$ which is $(2,0)$

Now we have to find the locus of point of intersection of a line from first family and a line from second family which are perpendicular to each other.
[image]
$$\angle ABC=90^\circ$$

Now one solution which comes to mind is that $(h,k)$ lies on circle and $A,B$ are the endpoints of diameter. In that case locus of $(h,k)$ will be

$$x(x-2)+y^2=0$$

Now I am wondering if there is any other locus which also satisfies the given properties?

Comment: One bit of classical projective geometry is this: If you specify a projective transformation from the pencil (circle) of lines through $P$ to the pencil of lines through $Q$, then the locus of the intersection points is always a conic. See Pedoe , *Geometry: A Comprehensive Course*, or pp. 308-310 of my text *Abstract Algebra: A Geometric Approach*.

Answer (score 1):

No, the circle with diametric ends as such is the only region where the lines can intersect at $90^o$. Hence the locus you arrived with is the only correct answer.